# django generic view update/create: update works but create raises IntegrityError

Tags: django, django-forms, django-generic-views

I'm using `CreateView` and `UpdateView` directely into `urls.py` of my application whose name is dydict. In the file `forms.py` I'm using `ModelForm` and I'm exluding a couple of fields from being shown, some of which should be set when either creating or updating. So, as mentioned in the title, `update` part works but create part doesn't which is obvious because required fields that I have exluded are sent empty which is not allowed in my case. So the question here is, how should I do to fill exluded fields into the file `forms.py` so that I don't have to override `CreateView`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to set your required fields somewhere. If you don't want them to be shown or editable in the form, your options are to set them in the view (by using a custom subclass of `CreateView`) or if appropriate to your design in the `save` method of the model class. Or declare an appropriate `default` value on the field in the model.

It would also work to allow the fields into the form, but set them to use `HiddenInput` widgets. That's not safe against malicious input, so I wouldn't do that for purely automated fields.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot exclude fields, which are set as required in the model definition. You need to define `blank=True`/`null=True` for each of these model fields.

If this doesn't solve your issue, then please show us the model and form definitions, so we know exactly what the code looks like.